# Python: Copy directories, not files, from multiple locations, overwriting if same name

Tags: python

I have a main folder netbooks_nbo which contain more dated folders.  I want to get the last seven folders (by last modified date) and copy them to somewhere on the C:\ drive.  Here's my current code:

Code looks like this:

```
import os
import distutils.core

def get_immediate_subdirectories(dir):
    return [os.path.join(dir, name) for name in os.listdir(dir)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, name))]

def main():
    path = "\\\\Network_Drive\\netbooks_nbo"
    all_dirs = get_immediate_subdirectories(path)
    all_dirs.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
    all_dirs = all_dirs[len(all_dirs)-7: len(all_dirs)]

    for i in all_dirs:
        for n in get_immediate_subdirectories(i):
            distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(n, "C:\\AllFiles")
            print "copied"+ n
```

The problem is that dir_util.copy_tree copies all the files, rather than the actual directories.  I want to preserve the directory structure.  I tried using  `shutil.copytree(src, dst)` but it just returns an Error because C:\AllFiles will already exist after one iteration of the for loop.  And `shutil.copy(src,dst)` doesn't work because of some bizarre permission error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the directory trees are not too large, you could pack each directory tree into an [archive file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/archiving.html) and then unpack each of the archive files to your destination.

Comment: Ha!  I was thinking of that very solution, but it just seems to kludgey.

Comment: I find it useful when working with various sets of command line utilities (some lacking a recursive copy, some with the destination on another machine).  I don't find it worth worrying about a small temporary archive file, but for larger sets, I often use a pipe between the archive/unarchive bits so it really is just a copy.  I think you really want rsync, but I found the archivers in the standard library first.